# Set process title more than 16 bytes on Linux

Tags: linux, process, system-calls

In Linux, changing process title is able to use prctl.
But it have restriction that name length is 16 byte.

> PR_SET_NAME (since Linux 2.6.9)
>       Set the process name for the calling thread, using the value in the location pointed to by (char *) arg2. The name can be up to 16
>   bytes long, and should be null-terminated if it contains fewer bytes.

my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/prctl.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
    int status;
    pid_t pid;
    char *p = "this is more than 16 bytes process name";
    prctl(PR_SET_NAME, p); // restriction of 16 byte
    if ((pid = fork()) == -1) {
        printf("%s\n", "fork error");
        return 1;
    }
    if (pid != 0) {
        wait(&status);
    }
    else if (pid == 0) {
        sleep(30);
    }
}
```

How to able to avoid this restriction in Linux?

Comment: If there's only a 16-character field in the kernel for this, what makes you think you can get around it?

Comment: only 16 bytes?
it looks like to cause collision of process title.

Comment: So? What is it used for that requires it to be unique?

Comment: Or for convenient to compare check some status (for example memory usage) in task manager like:
`myprocess - new library  beta ver` 
`myprocess - (stable)`

Can be easy to look if more characters able to use in process title.

Comment: That's not what it's intended for -- it's usually just the name of the program, isn't it?